# javascript equivalent way of passing variable to anonymous function

Tags: javascript

In php we can do something like this:

```
$foo = 1;
$bar = 2;
$fn = function() use ($foo, $bar) {
    return $foo;
};
$foo = 3;
echo $fn(); // gives 1
```

How to do it in javascript?

I try it like this, but failed:

```
var foo = 1;
var bar = 2;
var fn = function() { return foo; }.bind(foo,bar);
foo = 3;
console.log(fn()); // gives 3, instead of 1
```

Answer (score 2):

`bind` is a method to explicitly define the `this` value and the values passed to the initial arguments of the function.

The arguments that can be passed to a function are defined when the function is created.

```
var fn = function(foo) { console.log(foo) }
```

JavaScript doesn't have any features to modify what arguments a function accepts after it has been created.

The scope of a function is also defined when it is created and can't be changed later. If you don't shadow `foo` with an argument name, then it will read `foo` from the scope it is defined in.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var foo = 1;
var fn = function(foo) { return foo; }.bind({}, foo);

foo = 3;
console.log(fn());
```

or through context

```js
var foo = 1;
var fn = function() { return this.foo; }.bind({foo});

foo = 3;
console.log(fn());
```